# Problem with sending html email

Tags: c#, email

Why when i send html email it looks like:

[image]

but initial page is:

[image]

Here is code:

```
MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
                message.IsBodyHtml = true;
                message.Subject = subject;
                message.Body = body;

                foreach (MailAddress recipient in recipients)
                {
                    message.To.Add(recipient);
                }
                if (message.To.Count > 0)
                {
                    SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
                    smtp.Send(message);
                    return true;
                }
```

Html file contains css in head. 
http://pastebin.com/r5V6X4Ld

Comment: What is the content of `body`?

Comment: @mahesh: I can... Maybe blocked by your proxy?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that the `body` variable only contains the HTML code, but not the CSS or the images, because both are separate files.
Basically, you need to attach the images to the mail and change the HTML code of the body to point to the correct location. See [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/embedemailimages.aspx) for more info and sample code.

This might also be helpful: http://www.alistapart.com/articles/cssemail/

> **Problem:**
>
> Some clients rendered my email with no style whatsoever. I first attributed this to the stripping of styles, but I then discovered that the styles were clearly visible in the source code. I subsequently spent a good deal of time attempting to uncover the culprit, testing countless versions of the email. Alas, the problem was right under my nose: the styles weren’t being stripped — the dots (.) preceding their names were. Therefore, “.Feature {}” became “Feature {}”, resulting in a meaningless style definition.

**Solution:**

> I used class selectors, which ensured that each style would begin with a letter instead of a dot. So “.Feature {}” would become “td.Feature {}” or “div.Feature {}” (depending on the application). A somewhat mundane fix, but effective and (again) compliant.

Comment: NO. Html file contain css style.

Comment: @Daniel Hilgarth Thanks but images is not a problem. Problem is that page looks like css doesnt loaded.

Comment: Please post the content of `body`.

Comment: @Neir0: Thanks. Please see update to my answer. The provided link might help you.

Answer (score 0):

You have to refer your image with full path ie www.yourdomain/imagename.jpg etc and also have to give the class as inline styles